# Reset Button for iOS Countdown Timer (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am implementing a countdown timer and I am having an issue with the reset button. I get the error "Value of type '(UISlider) -> ()' has no member 'setValue'

```
@IBAction func sessionSlider(_ sender: UISlider) {
seconds = Int(sender.value)
sessionCountdownLabel.text = String("\(seconds) Seconds")
}


@IBAction func resetButton(_ sender: Any) {
timer.invalidate()
seconds = 30
sessionSlider.setValue(30, animated: true)
sessionCountdownLabel.text = String("\(seconds) Seconds")
}
```

Comment: `sessionSlider` seems to be your other function. Do you have an actual property (or outlet) that represents a `UISlider`?

Comment: sessionSlider was the name of the Slider object I gave when I connected it to my ViewController, so wouldn't that be the outlet as well?

New to this so I'm making quite a bit of simple errors.

Comment: There's a difference between the slider being connected to an `IBOutlet` in your code (if any) and connecting the slider's event to your `IBAction` function. Do you have an `IBOutlet` in your code with a type of `UISlder`?

Comment: Oh now I get what you meant I added an Outlet for the slider `@IBOutlet weak var sessionSliderOutlet: UISlider!` and have replaced `sessionSlider.setValue(30, animated: true)` with  `sessionSliderOutlet.setValue(30, animated: true)`

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out for me, much appreciated